# java heap space error for large array only in object but not in main method

Tags: java, arrays, out-of-memory

I am trying to read in around 76 million values into an array. I would expect a heap space exception, but defining large array in public static main method does not give exception while defining in some other class throws exception below is my code. Could anyone please explain the reason ?
This below code runs fine

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("emails.txt"));
    String line = "";
    int i= 1;
    Node[] emails = new Node[76000000];
    while((line = br.readLine())!= null){
        String[] strArray = line.split(",");
        Node n = new Node(strArray[1],Integer.parseInt(strArray[0]));
        emails[i] = n;
    i++;
    }
    System.out.println("done"); 
}
//Code for node class
public class Node implements Comparable {
   String val;
   int id;
   Node nxt;
   public Node(String val, int id){
     this.val = val;
     this.id = id;
     nxt = null;
   }
}
```

Now If put the main method into another class:

```java
public class newC {  
    runMainMethod() {  
        // same code as in above main method  
    }
}
```

This code immediately throw java heap space exception

Comment: Just wondering: is there a special reason why you want to keep those millions of entries in memory?

Comment: When you run `newC.runMainMethod()` has the allocation of `Node[] emails = new Node[76000000];` in `main` also happened? Do both pieces of code run? I.e. you don't show what you are doing when you run the code that has the OOM

Comment: @Jagemeister: Yes, to do some preprocessing before putting it in hadoop

Comment: @Cratylus: I copy pasted the same code from the public static main method ( in the question) and pasted it in the runMainMethod. I could run the code from the public static main method with out heap space error

Comment: @user3473627:So basically you are allocating `2*76000000`? One time in `main` and one time in your new method? You are not answering that. Are you deleting everything in `main`? So us your code example

Comment: This is a classic [XyProblem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). I suggest you process the file stream without loading the whole thing into memory.